# Laravel - How to add an event from a calender to OutLook Calender

Tags: laravel, outlook

I'm new to Laravel. I have got a problem while creating a new feature in a laravel website. I hope you can help me with it.
On the website, the user has an overview of all appointments in the calendar.
What needs to be created is: If the user clicks on an event in the calendar, that event can be added to his Outlook calender.
I am searching on the internet to get some information! from where I can start or which steps to take, but I can't figure it out.

Can you please give me some tips or keywords about what to do.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sagarrabadiya/outlook-php](https://github.com/sagarrabadiya/outlook-php) repository. It implements the [Microsoft Outlook REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/get-started) and able to create new events in calendar.

In order to install this repository to your Laravel project, use composer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't automate Outlook from a web browser. Only Internet Explorer allows dealing with COM objects. So, I don't think it will be an acceptable solution.

If your users deal with Exchange accounts you may consider using EWS (Exchange Web Services), see [Start using web services in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/start-using-web-services-in-exchange) or [Outlook REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/use-outlook-rest-api) in case of Office 365.